# How could I write this queries in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I'm very new to neo4j and to graph database in general. I'm prototyping an app, and I don't know how should i write these queries

I've this domain:

User
Restaurant
Review
TypeOfFood

So a Restarurant have one or many TypeOfFood, the User leaves reviews about restaurants. The User have some preferred foods, matching the TypeOfFood a restaurant sell. Also Users are related to each other with the typically friend relationship.

Some of the queries I'm trying to write:

- Give me all the restaurants that my friends have rated with 3 or more stars that make the kind of food I like (exclude those restaurants that I already reviewed)
- Suggest me friends I may know (I guess this should be something like "all the friends that are friends of my friends but no yet mine, order by something)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using Neo4j's [Cypher](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/cypher-query-lang.html) query language you could write your queries like this:

Selecting the top-20 best rated restaurants, sorted by stars and number of reviews

```
start user=(users,name,'Nico')
match user-[:FRIEND]->friend-[r,:RATED]->restaurant-[:SERVES]->food,
      user-[:LIKES]->food,user-[:RATED]->rated_by_me
where r.stars > 3
return restaurant.name, avg(r.stars), count(*)
order by avg(r.stars) desc, count(*) desc 
limit 20
```

Friends of a Friend

```
start user=(users,name,'Nico')
match user-[:FRIEND]->friend->[:FRIEND]->foaf
return foaf, foaf.name
```

You can execute these cypher queries in the [Neo4j Webadmin Console](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/tools-webadmin.html) on your dataset, but also in the neo4j-shell, remotely via the Cypher-Rest-Plugin  via [Spring Data Graph](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-graph/snapshot-site/reference/html/).

There is also a [screencast](http://video.neo4j.org/U2Y/introduction-to-cypher/) discussing similar queries in cypher.

You can also use [Gremlin](http://gremlin.tinkerpop.com), [Neo4j-Traversers](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/tutorials-java-embedded-traversal.html) or manual traversing via `getRelationships` if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I went to your SO profile to find a way to contact you, expecting a normal coder, but you're a rock star :)

Do you do consulting? or maybe you can put me in contact with someone?

Comment: Thanks for the praise. You can contact me by subscribing to the Neo4j mailing list. We at Neo Technology also do consulting.

Comment: Hi @MichaelHunger, I have posted one query (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721173/neo4j-user-suggestion-with-mutual-count/17831172?noredirect=1#comment26066269_17831172), can you help me out for this? and How do I subscribe you in mailing list. I want to know about your consulting and it's charges. Thanks