# neo4j - user suggestion with mutual count

Tags: neo4j, cypher, social-networking, mutual-friendship

I have created 5 nodes in neo4j as follows.

```
Node 1 {userid:1000, username: A, someOtherProperties...}
Node 2 {userid:2000, username: B, someOtherProperties...}
Node 3 {userid:3000, username: c, someOtherProperties...} 
Node 4 {userid:4000, username: D, someOtherProperties...} 
Node 5 {userid:5000, username: E, someOtherProperties...}
```

Node 1 connected with Node 2 & 3, and Node 2 connected with node 1, 3, 4

```
1 -> 2
1 -> 3
2 -> 1
2 -> 3
2 -> 4
3 -> 4
```

Now I want user suggestion for node 1 which contain those node which is not connected with 
it self with mutual count. I want result like this.

```
node id  userid  username  mutual count
-------  ------  --------  -------------
4    4000    D         2             (which is node 2 & 3)
5    5000    E         0
```

I had tried cypher query, but I didn't get success.

Comment: What query did you try? Can you share that?

Comment: Thanks @Luanne. I had tried following query : START user=node:node_auto_index("userid:*"), me=node:node_auto_index(userid = '92') 
WHERE user <> me 
WITH user
MATCH pMutualFriends=me-[:friends]->mf<-[?:friends]-user
RETURN  user.userid, user.UserName, COUNT(pMutualFriends) As MutualCount
Order by MutualCount desc;     I had forgotten to put '?' in relationship before, that I had corrected. I have got result what I expected, But I am not sure. Is it correct way or not?

Comment: So you are looking to for a user U, find all friends of friends U and the number of U's friends connected to the friends-of-friends? Not sure why E turns up in your example because no friends are connected to E. Maybe I misunderstood the purpose of your query?

Comment: No @Luanne. I want E also. I want all users, but It should be ordered by mutualcount maximum to minimum. I just want to show No Of Mutual friends between logged in user and other user. so, logged in user can sent invitation to that user. If new user can not have any mutual contact, though he/she can get suggestion as per his/her city or country. and one more thing, I have to show random 10 records. thank you.

Comment: Okay, if that's what you want then you're query is fine. Note that however it could really be expensive because you are matching all user nodes

Comment: ya @Luanne, that's true. because very first time this query has been taken 5-6 sec. to get result. then after it is returning result in 3-4 sec. but I think it is also very slow performance. because in my test data, it has just 200 records only. so, I don't know why it is performing very slow? Can I have to made any changes on this query or may be I have to look it for indexing?

Comment: And How can I create unique index on my userid, username, emailid?

Comment: did a graphgist on that, could you flesh that out for others to see and comment on it to update with your fork? Not sure I got it right :)  http://gist.neo4j.org/?6038792

Comment: thanks @PeterNeubauer for link. I have some doubt. I want result as i mentioned in my question. your result doesn't match with my expected result.

Comment: It's slow because you are touching the entire graph (in your case it has only users). Maybe you can change your logic to find friends of friends and append on a list of users with no friends (maybe index it or something to get it without a graph query)

Comment: As for uniqueness, you can create unique nodes like this http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/transactions-unique-nodes.html but as far as I know, you cannot create a unique "index" on the combination. Though if your nodes are unique, it implies your index should be

Comment: your link shows me to create unique node with JAVA. but I am using node.js. I can not get any clue to do this with node.js. do you have any idea to do this with node.js or cypher?

Comment: Hi @Luanne, still I am not able to get answer as expected. I think MATCH clause work as INNER JOIN in relational database. I want all node with mutual count. Can you help me?

Comment: Thought your query was already working?  START user=node:node_auto_index("userid:*"), me=node:node_auto_index(userid = '92') WHERE user <> me WITH user MATCH pMutualFriends=me-[:friends]->mf<-[?:friends]-user RETURN user.userid, user.UserName, COUNT(pMutualFriends) As MutualCount Order by MutualCount desc

Comment: @Luanne, this is my modified and working query : START user=node:node_auto_index(UserID = '1'), other=node:node_auto_index("UserID:*")
MATCH user-[:friends]-(frnd), pMutualFriends=user-[:friends]-mf-[:friends]-other
WHERE other.UserID <> 1 
AND other.FirstName =~ "(?i)dhar.*" 
RETURN frnd.UserID, other.UserID, other.UserName, other.FirstName, other.LastName, other.ImagePath, 
COUNT(distinct mf) AS mutualFriends
ORDER BY mutualFriends desc, other.FirstName LIMIT 20; but it shows only nodes which has mutual count. I also need node which has no mutual count. thanks for quick reply.

Comment: Can you please put a sample graph on console.neo4j.org otherwise it's really difficult

Comment: Ya sure @Luanne, but first I have to learn, how do I put graph. But I will try and let you know. but mean while you can see this link (http://docs.neo4j.org.cn/cypher-cookbook-mutual-friends-and-groups.html). I my case I want all node (eg. 1,2,3 and 4) with mutual count.

Comment: Hi @Luanne, I have tried. Please look at this link (http://console.neo4j.org/?id=h1p7it). I want node 2,3,4,5,6 (eg. user B,C,D,E,F) with mutual count between 1 and this nodes. If no mutual between 1 and node, then it will be return as 0 count.

Comment: Hi @Luanne, did you checked link?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to give me some time...will try to help out in my spare time :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34039/discussion-between-manish-sapkal-and-luanne)

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
START user=node:node_auto_index(name='A'), f=node(*) 
MATCH user-[r?:FRIEND*1..2]->(f) 
WITH DISTINCT r AS friendRelation,f 
RETURN count(friendRelation),f
```

Which will give you the number of friend relations to every other node with a depth 2 (friend of a friend)

Comment: Thanks @Luanne I don't need friend of friend, but I want mutual friend with node A

Comment: Sorry but I am pretty confused. Can you please define what you mean by a mutual friend? For node A in your graph console.neo4j.org/?id=h1p7it what are the expected results

Comment: sorry @Luanne, I am not good with english thats why I am not able to explain you properly. sorry again. I need all user list with mutual count. means In my case, node1 (username:A) is logged user, and want to search another users started with some word (eg. 'aakas.*'). and if some node exist with username 'aakas'. this records should be shown with mutual count. can you get me? or more need to explain you?

Comment: As per my query, I need node2(B) with 1 mutual count, rest come with 0 mutual count

Comment: Okay think I got it. So A has one friend in common with B i.e. C - is that it?

Comment: yes @Luanne, exectly, Is their any way to show you my data and cypher query? because my data has about 25000 uses and relation. so, can not able to explain exactly what i want to get result/

Comment: Let me see if I can change my query to first match your sample graph and then you can apply it to your actual graph and the results should be similar

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34172/discussion-between-luanne-and-manish-sapkal)